# Is it possible to make a dialog float above BrowserView in Electron?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, electron

So I'm trying to develop a browser with Electron, and I've made the tabs and address bar, but I'm having a problem when developing the downloading feature.

My expectation is to show a dialog after clicked the download list button beside the address bar, and the dialog's content is a list of downloaded/downloading items. It's not a seperate window, it's very much like Chrome's new download dialog.

But my dialog will be covered by the webpage, which is the `BrowserView`. I found [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16854) on Github which a contributor said in a few years ago that it's impossible.

Is it still impossible now? If that's the case, what is the best alternative approach to make this download dialog?

My browser's UI in written in Vue.js and loaded into the main `BrowserWindow`, here is the code I've tried:

```
interface ViewItem {
  view: BrowserView;
  id: string;
}

let mainWindow: BrowserWindow;
let views: ViewItem[] = [];
let activeViewId = '';

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    show: false,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    ...(process.platform === 'linux' ? { icon } : {}),
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: join(__dirname, '../preload/index.js'),
      sandbox: false
    }
  });

  const defaultUrl = 'https://www.electronjs.org/';
  const firstTabId = createTab(defaultUrl);

  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => updateActiveTab(firstTabId));
  mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', () => mainWindow.show());
  mainWindow.on('resize', () => updateActiveViewSize());

  if (is.dev) mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  if (is.dev && process.env['ELECTRON_RENDERER_URL']) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(process.env['ELECTRON_RENDERER_URL']);
  } else {
    mainWindow.loadFile(join(__dirname, '../renderer/index.html'));
  }
}

function createTab(url) {
  const view = new BrowserView();
  const id: string = getId();
  views.push({ view, id });

  registerMenu(view);

  activeViewId = id;
  mainWindow.setBrowserView(view);
  updateActiveViewSize(id);

  view.webContents.loadURL(url);

  view.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((details) => {
    createTab(details.url);
    updateViewsInfo();
    return { action: 'deny' };
  });

  view.webContents.on('did-navigate', (_, url) => updateViewUrl(id, url));
  view.webContents.on('did-navigate-in-page', (_, url) => updateViewUrl(id, url));
  view.webContents.on('page-title-updated', (_, title) => updateViewTitle(id, title));

  return id;
}
```